# How to grep all lines from one file in specific column in multiple other files?

Tags: text-processing, command-line, grep, bioinformatics

I have one file: combined.txt like this:

```
GO_GLUTAMINE_FAMILY_AMINO_ACID_METABOLIC_PROCESS
REACTOME_APC_CDC20_MEDIATED_DEGRADATION_OF_NEK2A
LEE_METASTASIS_AND_RNA_PROCESSING_UP
RB_DN.V1_UP
REACTOME_ABORTIVE_ELONGATION_OF_HIV1_TRANSCRIPT_IN_THE_ABSENCE_OF_TAT
...
```

and in my current directory I have multiple .xls files which are named like lines in combined.txt, for example: GO_GLUTAMINE_FAMILY_AMINO_ACID_METABOLIC_PROCESS.xls

In those .xls files I want to retrieve everything in column named: GENE_TITLE for which I have "Yes" in column named: "METRIC SCORE"

those files look like:

```
 NAME    PROBE   GENE SYMBOL     GENE_TITLE      RANK IN GENE LIST       RANK METRIC SCORE       RUNNING ES      CORE ENRICHMENT
row_0   MKI67   null    null    51      3.389514923095703       0.06758767      Yes
row_1   CDCA8   null    null    96      2.8250465393066406      0.123790346     Yes
row_2   NUSAP1  null    null    118     2.7029471397399902      0.17939204      Yes
row_3   H2AFX   null    null    191     2.3259851932525635      0.22256653      Yes
row_4   DLGAP5  null    null    193     2.324765920639038       0.2718671       Yes
row_5   SMC2    null    null    229     2.2023487091064453      0.31562105      No
row_6   CKS1B   null    null    279     2.0804455280303955      0.3555722       No
row_7   UBE2C   null    null    403     1.816525936126709       0.38350475      No
```

And in the output file I would have just in every line:

```
 GO_GLUTAMINE_FAMILY_AMINO_ACID_METABOLIC_PROCESS 51 96 118 191 193
<name of the particular line in combined.txt>  <list of all entries in GENE_TITLE which have METRIC SCORE=Yes>
```

What I tried so far is:

```
grep -iw -f combined.txt *.xls > out1
```

I also tried this but here I am not using information from combined.txt neither getting values labeled with "Yes" just extracting 5th column from all files

```
awk '{ a[FNR] = (a[FNR] ? a[FNR] FS : "") $5 } END { for(i=1;i<=FNR;i++) print a[i] }' $(ls -1v *.xls) > out2
```

this is maybe a little bit closer but still not there:

```
awk 'BEGIN {ORS=" "} BEGINFILE{print FILENAME} {print $5 " " $8} ENDFILE{ printf("\n")}'  *.xls > out3
```

I am getting something like:

```
GENE_TITLE GENE 1 Yes 4 Yes 11 Yes 23 Yes 49 Yes 76 Yes 85 Yes 118 No 161 No....
GENE_TITLE GENE 0 Yes 16 No 28 Yes 51 Yes 63 No 96 Yes 182 Yes 191 Yes
...
```

so my desired output would have instead of "GENE_TITLE GENE" the name of the file from where it did grab those values (without .xls suffix) : 0 Yes 16 No 28 Yes 51 Yes 63 No 96...not including the one which have "No"

#### UPDATE

I did get the file I needed but I wrote the ugliest code possible (see bellow). If someone has something a little bit more elegant please do share.

This is how I got it:

```
awk '{print FILENAME " "$5 " "$8}' *.xls  | awk '!/^ranked/' | awk '!/^gsea/'|  awk '!/^gene/' | awk '$3!="No"  {print $1 " " $2}' | awk '$2!="GENE_TITLE"  {print}' |awk -v ncr=4 '{$1=substr($1,0,length($1)-ncr)}1' | awk -F' ' -v OFS=' ' '{x=$1;$1="";a[x]=a[x]$0}END{for(x in a)print x,a[x]}'>out3

grep -iw -f combined.txt out3 > ENTR_combined_SET.txt
```

Comment: To be honest, this seems complicated enough that you might want to switch to  `python` (or a similar language). It will make your code more readable and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xargs -I {} awk '$8 == "Yes" { title = title OFS $5 } END { print substr(FILENAME,1,length(FILENAME)-4), title }' {}.xls <combined.txt
```

This uses `xargs` to execute an `awk` program for each name listed in your `combined.txt` file.

The `awk` program is given whatever names is read from the `combined.txt` file with `.xls` added onto the end of the name as its input file.

The `awk` program collects the data from the 5th column for each row whose 8th column is `Yes`.  This string is then printed together with the filename with its last four characters (the file name suffix) chopped off.

Comment: Hi How would I change this command so that it prints me file name as it is and 2nd column which is called  "PROBE", instead of "GENE_TITLE" that I have now?

Comment: @anikaM You would change `$5` to `$2` and use just `FILENAME` instead of `substr(...)`.

Comment: Is it like this: xargs -I {} awk '$8 == "Yes" { title = title OFS $2 } END { print FILENAME, title }' {}.xls < combined.txt

Comment: @anikaM I believe so, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# read combined.txt line by line
while read -r line; do
        # skip missing file ${line}.xls
        [ ! -f "$line".xls ] && continue

        # echo line and one space character (without newline)
        echo -n "$line " >> out

        # get 5th column if line ends with "Yes" and optional whitespace at end of line
        # replace newline '\n' with space ' '
        sed -nE 's/^\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+).*\sYes\s*$/\1/p' "$line".xls | tr '\n' ' ' >> out

        # add newline
        echo >> out
done < combined.txt
```

in one line:

```
while read -r line; do [ ! -f "$line".xls ] && continue; echo -n "$line " >> out; sed -nE 's/^\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+).*\sYes\s*$/\1/p' "$line".xls | tr '\n' ' ' >> out; echo >> out; done < combined.txt
```

Note that each line in `out` will have one additional space character at the end of the line.